# Repeated subsetting of the same matrix using apply in R

Tags: r, subset, apply

**Motivation**: I am currently trying to rethink my coding such as to exclude for-loops where possible. The below problem can easily be solved with conventional for-loops, but I was wondering if R offers a possibility to utilize the apply-family to make the problem easier.

**Problem**: I have a matrix, say `X` (`n x k` matrix) and two matrices of start and stop indices, called `index.starts` and `index.stops`, respectively. They are of size `n x B` and it holds that `index.stops = index.starts + m` for some integer `m`. Each pair `index.starts[i,j]` and `index.stops[i,j]` are needed to subset `X` as `X[ (index.starts[i,j]:index.stops[i,j]),]`. I.e., they should select all the rows of `X` in their index range. 
Can I solve this problem using one of the apply functions?

**Application**: (Not necessarily important for understanding my problem.) In case you are interested, this is needed for a bootstrapping application with blocks in a time series application. The `X` represents the original sample. `index.starts` is sampled as `replicate(repetitionNumber, sample.int((n-r), ceiling(n/r), replace=TRUE))` and `index.stops`is obtained as `index.stop = index.starts + m`. What I want in the end is a collection of rows of `X`. In particular, I want to resample `repetitionNumber` times  `m` blocks of length `r` from `X`.

**Example**:

```
#generate data
n<-100 #the size of your sample
B<-5 #the number of columns for index.starts and index.stops
     #and equivalently the number of block bootstraps to sample
k<-2 #the number of variables in X
X<-matrix(rnorm(n*k), nrow=n, ncol = k)

#take a random sample of the indices 1:100 to get index.starts
r<-10 #this is the block length 
#get a sample of the indices 1:(n-r), and get ceiling(n/r) of these 
#(for n=100 and r=10, ceiling(n/r) = n/r = 10). Replicate this B times
index.starts<-replicate(B, sample.int((n-r), ceiling(n/r), replace=TRUE)) 
index.stops<-index.starts + r

#Now can I use apply-functions to extract the r subsequent rows that are 
#paired in index.starts[i,j] and index.stops[i,j] for i = 1,2,...,10 = ceiling(n/r) and 
#j=1,2,3,4,5=B ?
```

Comment: Can you give a minimum working example with some (fake) data, say for n = 3 and k = 4 or something like this? Makes it easier to understand and solve...

Comment: Hey David, I hope this helps you!

Comment: Perhaps, you need to `Map(":", index.starts, index.stops)` and subset "X" accordingly?

Comment: Can you include your for-loop that you currently use? Im still trying to get my hear around what you are doing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably way more complicated than what you want/need, but here is a first approach. Just comment if that helps you in any way and I am happy to help.

My approach uses (multiple) *apply-functions. The first lapply "loops" over 1:B cases, where it first calculates the start and end points, which are combined into the take.rows (with subsetting numbers). Next, the inital matrix is subsetted by take.rows (and returned in a list). As a last step, the standard deviation is taken for each column of the subsetted matrizes (as a dummy function).

The code (with heavy commenting) looks like this:

```
# you can use lapply in parallel mode if you want to speed up code...
lapply(1:B, function(i){
  starts <- sample.int((n-r), ceiling(n/r), replace=TRUE)
  # [1] 64 22 84 26 40  7 66 12 25 15
  ends <- starts + r

  take.rows <- Map(":", starts, ends)
#   [[1]]
#   [1] 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82
#   ...

  res <- lapply(take.rows, function(subs) X[subs, ])
#   res is now a list of 10 with the ten subsets
#   [[1]]
#   [,1]        [,2]
#   [1,]  0.2658915 -0.18265235
#   [2,]  1.7397478  0.66315385
#  ...

  # say you want to compute something (sd in this case) you can do the following
  # but better you do the computing directly in the former "lapply(take.rows...)"
  res2 <- t(sapply(res, function(tmp){
    apply(tmp, 2, sd)
  })) # simplify into a vector/data.frame
#   [,1]      [,2]
#   [1,] 1.2345833 1.0927203
#   [2,] 1.1838110 1.0767433
#   [3,] 0.9808146 1.0522117
#   ...
  return(res2)
})
```

Does that point you in the right direction/gives you the answer?

Comment: David, this is great! I don't even think it's complicated, and the Map() command makes a whole lot of sense now that I see it. I really like the solution by which you obtain res/res2! 
Thank you also for the excessive commenting, that really helped me! :)

Comment: Always a pleasure. One last thing, if you want to speed up the code, you can use `snowfall` and `sfClusterApplyLB` to execute in parallel (have a look at a blog-article I wrote earlier: https://datashenanigan.wordpress.com/2015/09/23/simulating-backtests-of-stock-returns-using-monte-carlo-and-snowfall-in-parallel/).